# How does a motherboard convert the input voltage to the 12V of the PCI?

Tags: motherboard, pci

Has it a DC/DC converter inside? Are the 12V guaranteed to be 12.0V sharp?

Comment: The tolerance on the 12V line is +/- 5%.  So 11.4V to 12.6V.

Answer (score 1):

No, it won't be exactly 12V, because PCIe specs allow for 8% tolerance in the 12V supply at any load current that is within limits of the specs.

As computer ATX supplies have requirement of 5% tolerance for 12V output, it is highly unlikely that a motherboard would provide a separate DC-DC converter for the PCIe slots. The PCIe slots would simply be powered directly from the 12V coming from ATX power supply.